# Why Is Blender Eating Up My Hard Disk Space

Tags: system

I'm running v2.9.1 on Mac OSX 10.14.6 and I'm rapidly loosing hard disk space (roughly 80gb at the moment).

From what I can find, BVH caching is no longer a thing, I've set my temp files to somewhere local and there is nothing of note in there. I've disabled Cache Result in the Output Panel and trawled through files on my computer (including the hidden ones) but can't find the cause.

Any help would be very much appreciated as my Mac is grinding to a halt!

Comment: It seems like you're unable to find out where blender is storing some files?  Can't you search for "files created in past day"?  Then you can ask a more specific question.   If you are doing Physics (cloth, particles, etc), blender creates directories with many smaller files, one per frame.   This might be within the directory of your blend file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I'm able to search by date. Good shout on the physics, but unfortunately the model I'm working on is fairly straightforward.